# Проблема! Бот не выдает сообщение и ошибку

Tags: discord.py

Проблема в том, после написание команды !acc, мне нечего не выводит, не сообщение, не ошибку
Код:

```
async def __acc (ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    ping = client.ws.latency # Получаем пинг сервера
    with open("msg.json", "r") as f:
        ms = json.load(f)
    if member is None:
        coin = cursor.execute("SELECT coins FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]
        money = cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]
        rep = {cursor.execute("SELECT rep FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]}
        emb = discord.Embed( title = f'◟︎**Аккаунт** __{ctx.author.name}__◝︎', description = '', colour = discord.Color.dark_purple() )

        emb.set_author(name = ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
# попробуй так .-.
        with open("msg.json", "r") as f:
            ms = json.load(f)
        emb.add_field( name = 'MoonForums〡Лунный аккаунт', value = f'**__Ранг__** **аккаунта:** __{ctx.message.author.top_role.mention}__\n**Денег**: {money} \n**Койнов**: {coin}\n**Репутация:** {rep} \n**Ответил:** \n**Задал** **__вопросов__**: {ms[str(ctx.author.id)]}\n**Статус аккаунта:** **__Зарегистрирован__**', inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="ᅠ ᅠ ◟︎Баны〡Муты◝︎", value=f"Спам: 2 раза > 20 минут\nСпам: 3 раза > 30 минут\nСпам: 4 раза > бан ∞", inline=True)
        emb.add_field(name="ᅠ ᅠ ◟︎Подробности◝︎", value=f"◟︎Сервер: MoonForums◝︎\n◟︎Пинг сервера: {ping * 1000:.0f}ms◝︎\n◟︎Память сервера: 38MB◝︎", inline=True)
        emb.set_footer(text="◟︎Информация от: {}◝︎〡MoonForums〡Лунный форум".format(ctx.author.display_name))
        emb.set_thumbnail(url = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/971061734796312618/971814398299619348/46326568-removebg-preview.png")
        await ctx.send ( embed = emb)
        await ctx.message.delete()

    else:
        coin = cursor.execute("SELECT coins FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]
        money = cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]
        rep = {cursor.execute("SELECT rep FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]}
        emb = discord.Embed( title = f'◟︎**Аккаунт** __{member.name}__◝︎', description = '', colour = discord.Color.dark_purple() )

        emb.set_author(name = ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)

        emb.add_field( name = 'MoonForums〡Лунный аккаунт', value = f'**__Ранг__** **аккаунта:** __{ctx.message.author.top_role.mention}__\n**Денег**: {money} \n**Койнов**: {coin}\n**Репутация:** {rep} \n**Ответил:** \n**Задал** **__вопросов__**: {ms[str(member.id)]}\n**Статус аккаунта:** **__Зарегистрирован__**', inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="ᅠ ᅠ ◟︎Баны〡Муты◝︎", value=f"Спам: 2 раза > 20 минут\nСпам: 3 раза > 30 минут\nСпам: 4 раза > бан ∞", inline=True)
        emb.add_field(name="ᅠ ᅠ ◟︎Подробности◝︎", value=f"◟︎Сервер: MoonForums◝︎\n◟︎Пинг сервера: {ping * 1000:.0f}ms◝︎\n◟︎Память сервера: 38MB◝︎", inline=True)
        emb.set_footer(text="◟︎Информация от: {}◝︎〡MoonForums〡Лунный форум".format(member.display_name))
        emb.set_thumbnail(url = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/971061734796312618/971814398299619348/46326568-removebg-preview.png")
        await ctx.send ( embed = emb)
        await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: так должен же хендлер быть, не?

Comment: Смысле? какой хендлен?

Answer (score 0):

1. 

```
await ctx.send (embed = emb)
await ctx.message.delete()
```

Скорее всего вы отправляете `embed` и сразу его удаляете.

2)

```
rep = {cursor.execute("SELECT rep FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]}
```

Мне кажется там не нужны `{}` эти скобки

Comment: Нет, все работало, но когда я добавил репутацию, оно перестало работать, могу скинуть весь код > Kan0koᵒᶠᶠᶤᶜᶤᵃˡ#0339

Comment: rep = {cursor.execute("SELECT rep FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]}
Разве там нужны {} эти скобки?

Comment: Да, без этого будет отправлять только сообщение cursor.execute("SELECT rep FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(member.id)).fetchone()[0], а не цифры

Comment: Нет, вы пишите rep = {здесь уже код}
Эти скобки в начале и конце нужны разве?

Comment: Я поправил, все равно не работает

Comment: Убрали до else и после?

Comment: Смысле? Я не понял

Comment: Вы делаете проверку if member is not None: А потом else: и там, и там вы вводите переменную rep = {}